# Partition global Stack Exchange account/profile into sub-profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, network-profile

Now that the Stack Exchange network of sites is rapidly expanding, it would be nice to be able to disassociate a single (or multiple) SE sites from your Stack Exchange profile -- ideally to partition your global profile into sub-profiles.

As an example, some sites may be related to your professional career and you wouldn't necessarily want your questions/answers on other (hobby, personal) SE sites to be reflected in your public profile (e.g. if you share a link to a programming question that you posted to your work colleagues).

Is there a way to do this?  As far as I can see you can only disassociate ALL sites, or associate ALL sites, but there is nothing in between.

Ideally I would like to see the following:

- Use the same Open ID on all sites
- Share the same global inbox across all sites
- Provide fine tuning of how your accounts are associated, e.g.:

  - IT-related (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, ...)
  - Hobby-related (Home brewing, Gardening, ...)

People who looked at your Stack Overflow profile could see that you are also a member of SF and SU, but not that you were a member of the hobby-related sites.  Your hobby-related profiles would show no link with your IT-related profiles.

Comment: As far as I can tell, one of the two options mentioned here has been removed in the 2 years since this was posted (you can't even dissociate all site accounts anymore), making this an even more worthwhile request.